# Large mouse cursor in some applications since update to Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: mouse, kde, cursor, 23.04

I encounter a twice as large mouse cursor in some applications after updating Ubuntu from 22.10 to 23.04.
For instance, in `Dolphin` the cursor is approximately twice as large as in the built-in `Files`, and also white instead of black.
I suspect some scaling issues since I use only 4k UHD monitors with 200% scaling, maybe the mouse cursor gets scaled twice.

I encouter this issue also for other KDE applications such as `Kate` and `Konsole` as well as `TexStudio`.

Comment: "some applications". Which more than Dolphin? More information will help to see whether the issue may be with QT applications.

Comment: Add relevant information to the question itself (use "edit"). Do not use comments for that. Comments are there to help improve questions and answers on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding an environmental variable fixed this for me, and in 23.04 that means adding the variable so environment.d can find it. Since I want this to work system-wide anyway I just added it to /etc/environment:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb
```

It should also be possible to add it in ~/.config/environment.d/00-fix-qt.conf

See also: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/qt5-apps-do-not-use-gtk2-theme-in-ubuntu-23-04-beta/35047

Comment: Fixed, it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've noticed this strange behavior only in one app. Morbid grey hand over the window. Tried to run Tweaks while changing cursor themes, and icons, and played around with Accessibility settings, but nothing worked out.
Then I just purged the app and re-installed it though not with `apt-get` but `snap` and it worked!

Comment: Hm, interesting - I remember that there was also a time when there were some issues when firefox was migrated from snap to apt-get or vice-versa